# Error in establishing websocket connection

Tags: javascript, websocket, wss

I am using [`ws`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) npm in the server side, websocket in the client side.

When running this code from node-js it works fine, but running it from the browser gives the following error:

> ```
> failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
> ```

```js
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://domain:port', null, { 
  rejectUnauthorized: false 
});

ws.onerror = function (e) {
  console.log(e)
}

ws.onclose = function (e) {
  console.log(e)
}

ws.onopen = function () {
  console.log('connected ')
  ws.send(JSON.stringify({ msg: 'msg' }));
}
```

Comment: try with `'ws://domain:port'`

Comment: my domain is running under https.
when using ws,  the error indicates to use wss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` this looks to be a certificate issue. There are various certificates that a browser use. For eg. you can see the certificates in Mozilla Firefox in **Preferences > Privacy & Security > Certificates**, and you can explore which certificate is causing you the problem.

Make sure your API is pointing to the correct certificate

Comment: thank you so much, I was using the wrong certificate